# Best practice for sharing data between pages

Tags: static, uwp, windows-phone, persistence

I was wondering what the best practice is for sending variables like 'selectedItem' and so on between pages in UWP? Is it a good idea to just create a static global variable class that every Page knows of?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm going to sum up Microsofts ***Best Practice*** here:

**For simple data (like strings):**
Use the [`Frame.Navigate(TypeName, Object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh702394.aspx) method, where as the second argument should **always** be a string (even if it allows objects). The second argument can then be extracted from the [`NavigationEventArgs.Parameter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.navigationeventargs.parameter.aspx) in the [`Frame.Navigated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigated.aspx) event handler.

**For complex data (anything besides strings):**
You may choose from two options here, depending on the size and complexity of your app:

- Either manage a reference to any complex data inside your `App` class directly
- Or keep a reference to them in any kind of *Manager* class, that is a member of your `App` class. (e.g. `NavigationDataManager`).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Can you maybe give me a link to where you found these best practices, because I'm interested in reading about them all? :)

Comment: @DanielBross It's in a _Microsoft Virtual Academy_ course. It's at least in this [German course](https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/de-de/training-courses/grundlagen-f-r-windows-10-f-r-entwickler-11538), but should also be in this [English one](https://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/en-us/training-courses/a-developers-guide-to-windows-10-12618?l=IV8HDBpRB_9005095281).

Comment: Okay, thanks! Luckily I'm German too, so I should be able to understand both! :)

Comment: @Herdo, for the Frame.Navigate case, is there a similar alternative for passing multiple strings during navigation? Or can only *one* simple type be passed per navigation? Thx!

Comment: @bunkerdive It's stated by Microsoft that only `string` should be used. I gonna try if `string[]` works as well, later today.

Comment: @Herdo You saved me so much coding work... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Well in fact if you use MVVM approach you have all necessary info in ModelView class(es). In case you do not use MVVM just use a singleton class or even a static global class.