# How to share data among multiple views

Tags: c#, window, windows-10, uwp, multiple-views

In Windows 10 UWP it is possible to create multiple windows (aka views which contain a separate window and a thread) for a single app:

- [Show multiple views for an app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt622742.aspx)
- [Multiple views sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/MultipleViews)
- [Guidelines for multiple windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn434070.aspx)

But what is the right way to share data / objects among multiple views in UWP? No info on this is provided in MSDN. There is a good article on this topic: [Windows 10, UWP, Multiple Windows, ViewModels and Sharing State](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2015/09/16/windows-10-uwp-multiple-windows-and-sharing-state.aspx). The difficulty is that `App.xaml` is separately instantiated for each view. It's interesting to see what others are doing in a similar situation?

A similar question which relates to pages but not views: [(UWP) Best practice for sharing data between pages](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33237884/4383472)

Comment: I totally disagree with putting shared data in app.xaml or similar hacks. You should set up a decent architecture with services or repositories to handle such complex scenarios.

Comment: @Bart Why not to use [concurrent collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx) and some [synchronization primitives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228964(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @Romasz nothing wrong with them, "au contraire", but I would still go for a decent architecture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While working with this you have multiple views, but still one application. The most important thing here is mentioned at MSDN you have linked:

> Each window operates in its own thread.

This complicates a situation in case of sharing data. As you have one application, you can share some data in app class, but you must look out for few things:

- UI elements can be accessed only via *Dispatcher* thread and in this case the one that owns them (so you cannot share this),
- concurrent access to collections - as there are few threads that can simultaneously access/modify them, use [Thread-Safe collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx), also some [help here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997373(v=vs.110).aspx),
- in case of synchronization, you also may need [some primitives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228964(v=vs.110).aspx) to steer your application workflow,
- race conditions - design your app with caution.

Some more help you can find at many blogs/posts. For example at [Alabhari's one](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).